# How can I get access_token with authorization code of facebook business account

Tags: facebook, oauth, instagram

I'm trying to make instagram business account login logic in my app, expecting to store user's facebook long-term-access-token in my database.

I succeeded in obtaining an authentication code by displaying the login page and redirecting to my server after logging in. I use api which described in "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/business-login-for-instagram".

However, I could not find an API to exchange the authentication code for an access token.

There is also a method to directly obtain an access token from the link, but I found that only the browser can parse the query string since it is preceded by a '#'.

**I am curious about the API to convert the auth code to an access token.** Thank you.

For your information, I am using NestJs server.

```
const url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth';

    const params = {
      client_id: this.config.getOrThrow('INSTAGRAM_CID'),
      redirect_uri: `${this.baseUrl}/instagram/oauth/callback`,
      display: 'popup',
      scope: 'instagram_basic',
      response_type: 'code',
    };

    return `${url}?${qs.stringify(params)}`;
```

Comment: Same as with the standard Facebook login, I would assume? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow#confirm

Answer (score 1):

I also got this issue, and my server just doesn't receive anything after the '#' char.

My solution was to use in '/dialog/oauth' API, the 'response_type' parameter 'code' instead of 'token', that case is return in the parameters of the redirect url '?code=[some code]' without the '#' char.

Then you need to use POST to /oauth/access_token API for exchange the 'code' with an 'acess_token'.